# How to deal with UnicodeDecodeError while reading a file?

Tags: python, text, file-handling, codec, textreader

SNIPPET:

```
with open("sample.txt", 'r') as f:
filedata = f.read()
```

ERROR that I get:
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
  1 `with open("sample.txt", 'r') as f:`
```

----> 2     `filedata = f.read()`
3

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)

```
 21 `class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):`
 22     `def decode(self, input, final=False):`
```

---> 23         `return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]`
24
25 `class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):`

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1768: character maps to

Please help me to understand what is the cause of this error and how it can be solved.
THANK YOU.

Comment: By specifying the correct codec. Your system default is not the right encoding for the file. We don't know what codec is correct however.

Comment: it worked using this format ----> open(path, mode, encoding='UTF8') thanks